# Execute AT commands to receive call in php

Tags: gsm, at-command

I'm new to PHP and want to develop Complaint Management System, First of all connect to GSM device with computer and access in PHP, receive calls through AT Commands in PHP.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php if your on Unix you can also just open the corresponding file descriptor for the device in question using fopen,fwrite etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to show what you tried so far and where you got stuck. It's not the purpose of stack overflow to write code for you but to gain an understanding of something in code.

Comment: require "php_serial.class.php";
$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("COM4");
$serial->confBaudRate(115200);

// Then we need to open it
$serial->deviceOpen();

// To write into
$serial->sendMessage("AT+CMGF=1\n\r"); 
$serial->sendMessage("AT+cmgs=\"+92234444444\"\n\r");
$serial->sendMessage("sms text\n\r");
$serial->sendMessage(chr(26));

//wait for modem to send message
sleep(7);
$read=$serial->readPort();
$serial->deviceClose();

Comment: Your almost there, same style but use the command answer or consult the device manual... https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://michaelgellis.tripod.com/modem.html&ved=2ahUKEwigo_bSsZvcAhXsYt8KHTxNCKAQFjADegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3ELOVMc2bZU-Dt_13n7fOw